# Останется ли запятая, если убрать местоимение?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

*Ты пошел туда(,) и ты нашел эту книгу.*

В этом предложении две грамматические основы, следовательно, запятая нужна. Но что будет, если во второй части предложения убрать местоимение "ты"? Останется ли она?

Answer (score 2):

Если во второй части этого *сложносочинённого* предложения (у него две основы: подлежащее "ты" со сказуемым "пошёл" и подлежащее "ты" со сказуемым "нашёл") убрать местоимение "ты", то оно станет *простым с однородными членами* (подлежащее — "ты", сказуемые — "пошёл" и "нашёл"). Тогда **запятая не нужна**.

Поэтому верно будет так.

*Ты пошёл туда и нашёл эту книгу*.